# Unable to get response from Spotify API in Angular app

Tags: angular, spotify

I'm getting the following error when I try to get json response from a Spotify API call:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=eminem&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist&market=US. Request header field Access-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have registered my app and used the code here (authorizaton code) https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples to generate Access token against my `client_id` with `redirect_url` set to `http://localhost:8888/callback`.

I tried using this access token in my Angular service in the following way:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Token': 'My-Access-Token' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

@Injectable()
export class ServicesService {
  private searchUrl: string;
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  searchMusic(str: String, type='artist'){
    this.searchUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query='+str+'&offset=0&limit=20&type='+type+'&market=US'
    return this._http.get(this.searchUrl, options)
            .map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
```

But as mentioned above its giving me the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a service or component? Seems like an odd mix of both?

Comment: My bad. It's supposed to be a service. I am updating it. I'd put the code in a component by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Altough I'm not familiar with the Spotify API this looks like the OAuth2 Implicit Grant Flow which uses the bearer token scheme.

As stated in [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) the token has to be transmitted in the `Authorization`-Header.

> When sending the access token in the "Authorization" request header field defined by HTTP/1.1 [RFC2617], the client uses the "Bearer" authentication scheme to transmit the access token.

> For example:

> `GET /resource HTTP/1.1`
> `Host: server.example.com`
> `Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM`

> [...]

> Clients SHOULD make authenticated requests with a bearer token using the "Authorization" request header field with the "Bearer" HTTP authorization scheme.

In your code, you are doing

```js
const headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Token': 'My-Access-Token' });
```

and the error you get says that the `Request header field 'Access-Token' is not allowed`.

Assuming the Spotify API adheres to the standard (I would be surprised if they didn't) your header should look like this:

```js
const access_token = 'YourAccessToken'
const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token });
```